# Adoptive Storage on Galaxy S7 edge

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a S7 edge. When I plug it into my pc it reads 2 separate volumes under phone, 32gb for S7 and 128 for sd. I'm able to freely transfer data between the phone's internal storage and the sd card and the computer. Then I went ahead and turned on the adoptable storage on my device. I then plugged my phone back into the computer but now it only reads 32gb of internal(phone) storage only, not the additional 128gb=160gb. I unplugged my phone from the computer and went into the device storage. It showed that I had 138gb(22gb was already being used by the device). Then the phone asked me if I was ready to migrate data from the internal storage to the sd. I wasn't sure what to do so. I didn't want to migrate data then not be able to access them through my pc or laptop so I canceled then reformatted the sd card as a external storage. I want to turn on adoptable storage but need to know why when I first attempted to do so my pc only saw 32gb instead of 160gb(32gb+128)? Was I suppose to migrate data in order for it to read 160gb? Is it normal for my pc to only see 32gb on the device but will still be able to access ALL of my data through my pc or will it only see the 32gb and whatever the phone decides to store on the sd will only be visible on the phone. One final question...if I'm only able to transfer files from the actual 32gb on the phone will I be able to transfer the other files,data stored on the sd through NFC or Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

It's because once the sd card is converted to adoptable, the pc will no longer see it. Only the original 32g will be recognized, but you will still have all of the extra space correctly. You'd have to transfer items to the main storage, then move them to the adoptable storage from the phone.